# Can android os support lcd display with spi interface?

Tags: android, spi

I installed android OS 5.0 on my Raspberry Pi, and I want to connect LCD display to it via the spi interface. Is it possible?

Comment: Might be worthwhile to post the question at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-rpi

Comment: In general the answer is yes, but it depends on the LCD.  What LCD are you using?

Comment: so, did it work? and how?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, yes.  In Android, the question about whether or not an LCD will work, and what you'll have to do to set it up, is really a Linux question.

Do you have drivers for the LCD? If you have drivers, and can build them into your kernel, and configure them correctly, they will in general expose an interface to /dev/fb. Android will automatically find that interface and use it as your display.